# Using plus equals operator with bytes

Tags: kotlin

The code below gives me the following error.

Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.Int but kotlin.Byte was expected

```
var temp: Byte = 0
var temp2: Byte = 1
temp += temp2
```

Is there any way around this in kotlin or am I not allowed to use the += or -= operators with Byte? Is plus equals overloaded for Long and Int but not Byte and Short?

Comment: It looks like operator overloading for assignment  uses plus() if plusAssign() is missing and does a type check. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html

Comment: Found issue in kotlin project not sure if it will be resolved. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7907

Answer (score 3):

According to [kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-byte/) Byte's plus/minus operations with other Byte will result in an Int. So while you think it is weird try to add Byte with value of 255 to other Byte with calue of 255 ;)

I think they made it on purpose. If you are certain that your result is still within Byte bounds then just use Int.toByte() and the end of the calculations.

Comment: You found the problem but it seems to me that plus and minus should return Byte and Short rather than int. I am currently doing temp = (temp + temp2).toByte() in my code though I would rather use the += operator.

Comment: What should happen if there is an overflow after addition? Should it be automatically truncated to byte or let it be an overflow? Kotlin's primary goal is to make developer's life safer (hence the new approach to nullability) and in my opinion the issue you have encountered is exactly such case.

Comment: @R4J True, though the same could be said for `Int`s and even `Long`s. Not saying I agree that `Byte` + `Byte` should return a `Byte`, just that by that logic `Int` + `Int` should return a `Long`.

Plus, there are reasonable use cases where overflow is desired.

Comment: Yes. There is no obvious choice I guess.